# Adding columns to view in T-SQL using while loop

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, while-loop

I'm currently cleaning up a few queries in my SQL views.

In one view a number of columns are generated using the following syntax

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Navn = '000100' THEN Vaerdi ELSE 0 END) AS '000100',
SUM(CASE WHEN Navn = '000110' THEN Vaerdi ELSE 0 END) AS '000110',
SUM(CASE WHEN Navn = '000115' THEN Vaerdi ELSE 0 END) AS '000115',
```

The list goes on and becomes quite extensive so I'd like to put this into a while loop.

Something like

```
WHILE (i in ('000100','000110','000115')
SUM(CASE WHEN Navn = i THEN Vaerdi ELSE 0 END) AS i,
END
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

Using the PIVOT function, I was able to accomplish my goal

```
WITH dataTable AS (
        SELECT 
        *
        FROM dbo.table
        WHERE Navn IN ('000100', '000110')
    )
SELECT * 
    FROM dataTable
PIVOT
        (
            SUM(Vaerdi)
FOR[Navn] IN (['000100],[000110])
)
    AS p
```

Comment: I think your question is restricted, _using while loop_, no?